How to test that a method was called exactly once with specific arguments?
I'm aware of toHaveBeenCalledWith and toHaveBeenNthCalledWith, but I want a call with certain parameter exactly once (or, more generally, N times). How do I check that? In other words, I care about number of calls and about arguments passed, but not about order of calls.
If I'd try to name a function to do such check, it would be e.g. toHaveBeenCalledTimesWith.

Combine toHaveBeenCalledTimes and toHaveBeenCalledWith.

@jonrsharpe It won't work because it sets no limit on number of calls with particular argument value. Also it won't be a sustainable solution. A method in question can be called an arbitrary amount of times with other arguments. So the test case would need to be updated each time another call is added.

At a certain point you probably just want to assert on the mock's call array. Or extend expect to do that with the matcher you want. Or refactor so you don't have to write such an implementation-dependent test. But without the context it's hard to say what a good approach might look like.

@jonrsharpe ...or implement the needed check function and propose as MR to Jest. I'll probably try.

You can use expect.extend to add the toHaveBeenCalledTimesWith matcher to Jest.
e.g.
index.test.js:
export function toHaveBeenCalledTimesWith(received, times, ...args) {
  const { printReceived, printExpected, matcherHint } = this.utils;

  const actual = received.mock.calls[0];
  const invokedTimes = received.mock.calls.length === times;
  const pass = invokedTimes && this.equals(args, actual);

  return {
    pass,
    message: () => {
      return pass
        ? matcherHint('.not.toHaveBeenCalledTimesWith', 'received', '') +
            '\n\n' +
            `Expected mock to be invoked ${times} times other than ${received.mock.calls.length} times or ${received.mock.calls.length} times with ` +
            `arguments other than ${printExpected(args)}, but was invoked ` +
            `${printReceived(received.mock.calls.length)} times with ${printReceived(...actual)}`
        : matcherHint('.toHaveBeenCalledTimesWith') +
            '\n\n' +
            (invokedTimes
              ? `Expected mock function to have been called ${times} times with ` +
                `${printExpected(args)}, but it was called with ${printReceived(...actual)}`
              : `Expected mock function to have been called ${times} times, but it was called ` +
                `${printReceived(received.mock.calls.length)} times`);
    },
    actual: received,
  };
}

expect.extend({ toHaveBeenCalledTimesWith });

describe('first', () => {
  test('should pass 1', () => {
    const fn = jest.fn();
    fn('a');
    fn('a');
    fn('a');
    expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledTimesWith(3, 'a');
  });
  test('should pass 2', () => {
    const fn = jest.fn();
    fn('a');
    fn('a');
    fn('a');
    expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledTimesWith(2, 'a');
  });
});

Test result:
 FAIL  stackoverflow/78977962/index.test.js
  first
    √ should pass 1 (2 ms)                                                                                                                                                        
    × should pass 2 (1 ms)                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                  
  ● first › should pass 2                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                  
    expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledTimesWith(expected)

    Expected mock function to have been called 2 times, but it was called 3 times

      42 |     fn('a');
      43 |     fn('a');
    > 44 |     expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledTimesWith(2, 'a');
         |                ^
      45 |   });
      46 | });
      47 |

      at Object.toHaveBeenCalledTimesWith (stackoverflow/78977962/index.test.js:44:16)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                    
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total                                                                                                                                          
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.836 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

